# Java: How to call super method from inner in-place class

Tags: java, callback, overriding, super

I have base class *Foo* with method *spam* and class *Bar* which overrides *spam*. I need to call *spam* of base class in method of some callback object which is defined in-place:

```
public class Foo {
    public void spam() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    public void spam() {
        objectWhichRequireCallback(new Callback {
            @Override
            public void onCallback() {
                super.spam();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This code is not working because *super* is related to *Callback*, not *Bar* class. Is it possible to call super method from object defined in-place?

Comment: Have you tried this.Foo.super.span()?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    public void spam() {
        objectWhichRequireCallback(new Callback {
            @Override
            public void onCallback() {
                Bar.super.spam();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT** : Sorry. DIdn't realize the method names are the same.

Comment: [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079600/java-how-to-call-super-method-from-inner-in-place-class) ;-)

Comment: I was sure that I tried this approach before asking question, but Eclipse gave me error. It seems that I was inattentive.

Now I retried. It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try this: `Bar.super.spam();`

`Bar.this.spam();` is compiled but it will cause infinite recursion because you call the same spam() itself.

Comment: Everybody loves a good Stack Overflow. I mean, we're here, after all.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a wrapper function for this, in Bar

```
public class Bar...

    public void mySuperSpam(){
        super.spam();
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be mySuperDuperSpam? :)